# Best way to insert users authorization on standard OSGi with Apache Karaf container and Play framewok

Tags: java, authorization, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle

my web application based on standard OSGi with three different bundles that expose the API Rest (CXF library) for back-end otherwise Play framework for Front-end that calls the api exposed from three bundles before cited. Actually there is already authentication process by SSO and password with in front of an Apache proxy configured with virtual host listened on a port defined. How and where can I insert authorization layer to cover all three bundles that expose the API services ? What is your advise ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a CXF interceptor . Just implement/override the common CXF interceptors to customize the authentification process.